# How to handle nominal data in scikit learn, python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-mining, categorical-data

I am new to data mining. I have a data set which includes directors' names. What is the right way to convert them to something that Scikit learn estimators can use without problem?

From what I found on the internet I thought that sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder is the right choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what type of model you're using, `make_pipeline(LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder)` or `pd.get_dummies`) is the usual choice, and can work well with classifiers from either `linear_model` or `tree`. `LabelEncoder` on its own would another choice, although this won't work well unless there's a natural ordering on your labels (like level of education or something) or unless you're using very deep trees, which are able to separate individual labels.

Comment: I am gonna convert "names of directors" to integers, and hence names have no ordering (do they?), then I should use OneHotEncoder?

Comment: yep that's correct, i've edited my answer with a little more detail

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think LabelEncoder would be the right choice. Following example is from Scikit-Learn document.

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(["paris", "paris", "tokyo", "amsterdam"])
list(le.classes_) # ['amsterdam', 'paris', 'tokyo']
le.transform(["tokyo", "tokyo", "paris"]) # array([2, 2, 1]...)
list(le.inverse_transform([2, 2, 1])) # ['tokyo', 'tokyo', 'paris']
```